# What is the maximum number of shaders I can have in OpenGL 4?

Tags: opengl, shaders

What is the maximum limit of shaders I can have on the GPU?

With 1000 different objects, I might have 1000 * 5 shaders (vertex, tcs, tes, geo, frag) on the GPU at a time. Though only one will be active at once, I wonder what the upper limit is.

Comment: Typically if you have 1000 objects you don't have 1000 shaders.  You'll have maybe 2 or 3, using 1 shader to draw 200, 1 to draw 500 and 1 to draw 300, or whatever.  There's nothing in OpenGL that requires use to have a separate shader per object.

Comment: but in case if i have something specific object configuration in the shader as uniform then i have to use new shader for the object. the question is should i use new shader even if i have only one uniform specific to the object?

Comment: @BKC: I am having a hard time understanding you, but I think you may be discussing a situation that would benefit from Uniform Buffer Objects. You can bind a uniform or an array of uniforms along with your model instances and drastically reduce the number of unique shader programs you really need by paramaterizing a lot of things.

Comment: Uniform Buffer Objects are definitely a good idea, but are a bit complicated to set up. You can also just change the uniforms using `glUniform*` between objects. The cost of changing between shaders is very high compared to updating a uniform.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no specific upper limit on the number of shaders that can be created.  Many games do have thousands of individual shaders.

With *very* large numbers of shaders, it's conceivable you could run out of GPU memory to store the binary code for all of them, but that would probably require millions of shaders.

Comment: The absolute hard limit for number of shaders is typically [2,147,483,647](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#In_computing).  (Although potentially could be as high as [9,223,372,036,854,775,807](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807#In_computing), depending on the size of the `GLuint` type).  In practice, you're going to run out of GPU memory before you hit those numeric limits, though.  :)

Comment: @TrevorPowell Since it's a uint, shouldn't that be 4294967295? ;)

Comment: ...I'll get my coat.